# Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response with MIME type application/json

Tags: reactjs, ajax, spring-boot, microservices, cross-origin-read-blocking

calling service from reactjs to spring boot. getting below error
Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type application/json

react code:

```
fetch(URL, {method: 'GET',
            contentType: 'application/json',
            mode: 'no-cors'
          }).then (function (response) { return response.json()})
            .then(function (json) {debugger;console.log(json)})
            .catch(function (error) {debugger;console.log(error)});

spring code:

    @GetMapping(path="/user/{aid}", produces= {"application/json"})
    public Optional<User> getUser(@PathVariable int aid) {
        return userRepo.findById(aid);
    }
```

error message:

> Cross-Origin Read Blocking (CORB) blocked cross-origin response  with MIME type application/json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow CORS from your spring code app. Hope this helps.[Enabling Cross Origin Requests for a RESTful Web Service](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors/)

Comment: as mentioned in that url, i added below line but no luck.
@CrossOrigin(origins = <client url>)

Answer (score -1):

application is expecting the header and you are passing different header,
for example : spring want application/json header and your passing text/html

React code :

```
fetch(url, { 
method: 'POST', 
headers: {'Content-Type':'application/json'},
 body: JSON.stringify(data)})
```